# Need to get a list of names (with just 1 instance of each name) from an array with multiples of each name

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I've googled but am unable to find a solution - looking for some help.

I have a database that includes various locations and distances between them:

```
beg_location    end_location    miles
pointA          pointB          2
pointA          pointC          3
pointB          pointA          2
pointB          pointC          1
pointC          pointA          3
pointC          pointB          1
```

I am using MagicalRecord to interface with CoreData - I just need to figure out how to best create an array containing each name (i.e. "PointA, pointB, pointC")

Here is my code:

```
LocationMiles location;
//Create ResultsController
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedLocationsController = [LocationMiles MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"beg_location" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:@"end_school" delegate:nil];
//turn controller into array
NSArray *fetchedLocations = [fetchedLocationsController fetchedObjects];

//go through array
for (location in fetchedLocations){
 NSLog(@"Here is a location: %@", location.beg_location);
}
```

Currently it gives me results - but they results are similar to:
Here is a location: pointA
Here is a location: pointA
Here is a location: pointB
Here is a location: pointB

I just want to get the array to read as pointA, pointB, pointC so I should have only 3 locations (I will be putting those into a UIPickverview later).

I'm sure something in my logic is just faulty here - I just can't figure out what.

Comment: The issue is that each point appears multiple times in the array. So if I removed the log text and had it print the array it would read: pointA, pointA, pointB, pointB, pointC, pointC - that is what I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faulty logic is on the type of objects you put in your array:

- `NSArray *fetchedLocations` is an array of `LocationMiles`
- What you
  want is an array of `NSString`

Also, you want a collection of object with no duplicate. This is what `NSSet` is.

```
// NSSet ensures there's only one occurence of each object
NSMutableSet *locationsStrings = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

//go through array and add the field you're interested in into set
for (location in fetchedLocations){
   [locationsStrings addObject:location.beg_location];
}

// make whatever use of locationsStrings you need
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I now have a NSSet with all the schools listed just once - just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
[fetchedLocationsController.fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
```